# have+since+past participle

Tags: grammar, since

> Few believed this technology had a future given the seemingly insurmountable immunity barriers and the fear of transmitting animal viruses to man. But progress in the biotechnologies has **since** brought some dramatic results.

I couldn't understand why they used "since" in this way?

Comment: **Since** the time that the technology was first invented.

Answer (score 2):

The "progress in the biotechnologies" occurred **after** the time when "Few believed this technology had a future" (probably soon after the technology was developed).  The word "since" is used to indicate that time sequence. A fuller form with the exact same meaning would be:

> But progress in the biotechnologies has **since then** brought some dramatic results.